# Indexing a Calculated Persisted VArBinary(Max) Column and Use In Access 2003 With ODBC

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, indexing, odbc

I am attempting to index and reference two tables with hash values that are created with persistence on SQL Server. My calculation is:

```
(hashbytes('sha1',((([AddressLine1]+[AddressLine2])+[City])+[State])+[Zip]))
```

The columns are all of Varchar Type.

I create an index on the calculated column and then attempt to link to SQLServer through ODBC, but I receive this error:

```
Invalid field Definition 'FIELDNAME' in definition of index or relationship
```

What could be the cause of this and how could I fix it?

**Edit**

I'm not permitted to share my information about the table definition, but the only key I need and have is the Primary key, which is a surrogate key. The calculated field forces a varbinary(max) type and allow nulls.

The test index is as follows

```
USE [KMC_MailingData]
GO

SET ARITHABORT ON
GO

SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
GO

set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
GO

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO

/****** Object:  Index [test]    Script Date: 08/08/2013 11:09:48 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [test] ON [dbo].[AddressStaging] 
(
    [calculatedHash] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: This is not enough information. Please can you provide the field definitions of both tables and the definition of their indexes. I suspect you are probably missing a key somewhere or the field type is something that access doesn't agree with..

Comment: Try to connect to the server with ADO using the sql driver as the Jet engine does funny things with the binary column

Comment: @twoleggedhorse, Edited the question. Also, I link the table using the Link Tables GUI in the object browser(tables,Queries,Forms,etc), and this is where the error happens.

Comment: Are you connecting to SQL using ADO.net or OLEDB through ODBC?

Comment: We use DSNs, actually, to link to the database.

Comment: Last question, what version of Access are you using?

Comment: I thought so, wasnt 100%, relatively new to a lot of the things I have been dealing with. Version is stated in the title, 2003 SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access [translates VARBINARY(MAX) into an OLE Object](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/import-or-link-access-to-sql-server-data-HA010341762.aspx#BM5) which unfortunately [cannot be indexed](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/about-data-types-and-field-sizes-mdb-HP005187521.aspx) in Access. Although it's a bit of a pain, it looks like you'll have to just use the tables without a relationship defined in Access. JetSQL and ODBC has a fair few limitations and this appears to be one of them.

Comment: That's pretty awful. Thanks for your help, that ruins quite abit.